# Installing Windows 10 in VirtualBox and in MBM

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, partitioning, windows-10-preview

I want to be able to test out Windows 10 in VirtualBox so that I don't have to reboot to switch to my main computer, however, it would be nice if I could also, when booting, boot directly into Windows 10 without the need for VirtualBox.

So basically, I want to be able to have Windows 10 on a partition, which can be booted directly or booted in VirtualBox.

Is there a way to go about this?

If so, does anyone know the steps required to achieve this and if there are there likely to be any problems?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically possible: Yes
In practice: No.

When you boot virtual box you will have different *hardware* than when you boot from the bare metal. This will confuse windows, which tend to store its hardware configuration so it can boot faster.

<sup>(Explicitly mentioning windows since other operating systems like FreeBSD or Linux do not do this and it would work for them. The price for that is a slower boot time)</sup>

You might get around that by assigning a real partition to contain the disk information in virtual box and always running sysprep before switching to new *hardware*. However this is extremely bothersome and basically comes down to repeating part of the windows installation whenever you switch between virtualized hardware and the bare metal.

A second way around that it by using VT-D and assigning real hardware to the OS in the VM. That requires a CPU with VT-D (or its AMD equivalent) and extra hardware. (e.g. one graphics card to boot your old OS, one to show in both real win10 and in the virtual box.  That might be done as a theoretical exercise, but doing this for real means you basically have the hardware for two PCs.

Comment: Well, I don't like this answer, because it's not what I wanted to hear. But thanks for putting it so clearly.

Answer (score -1):

You should use (for example) application as: Acronis True Image or Norton Ghost or another image creating

Run this program in VBox session (in Windows 10 guest) from start CD/image.

Make image this guest (for example) to network disk.

Next - restore these images to clean disk.

And run computer from this disk.

It should be run :-). But maybe is not run :-(.